# Redux Store Shared among test cases

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a util class which looks like this:

```
    mountGk = (component, appReducer) => {
        let store = createStore(appReducer);
        return [
            mount(
                    <Provider store={store}>
                    {intl(component)}
                    </Provider>
                 ),
            store
        ];
    }
}
```

It is used in my mocha test cases like this:

```
        const component = (
            <SelectUsers input={input}/>
        );
        [wrapper, store] = mountGk(component, appReducer);
```

Suppose I have 2 test cases which both use mountGk. In one of them, I modified the state like this:

```
store.getState()['some']['state']= ['1', '2']
```

Now the problem is I see the same value ['1', '2'] in the other test case even though I'm not setting it.

My concern now is createStore is not thread safe. If so, I can't write test cases for my React app. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. Actually the problem was because I modified the state without spread operator (or creating a new object). Solution:

```
            let iState = store.getState()['some'];
            iState = {
                ...iState,
                state: ['1', '2']
            };
            store.getState()['some'] = iState;
```

Explanation: store.getState()['some'] is actually the key to one of my reducer functions. Now a reducer function looks like this.

```
const initialState = {
    users: []
};

const ga_food_upload = (state= initialState, action) => {
// some code
}
```

It means when you do store.getState()['some']['state']= ['1', '2'], you actually change the const variable initialState and this affects other test cases.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should not modify your state like that. State is never modified directly in Redux, and certainly not by by calling **get** state. To modify state, you dispatch actions.

If you're using the same state in two tests in the same suite, that's because you're not calling again your `mountGk` function in **each** test, which you should be doing.

Each test should get a fresh environment! Because your function recreates the store, each time you call it you get a new store.

If you want to reuse the variables names between tests, have something like this:

```
let store, wrapper

beforeEach(() => {
  const [newStore, newWrapper] = mountGk(...)
  store = newStore
  wrapper = newWrapper
})

it('does something', () => {
  store.dispatch(...)
})
```

Comment: because it's test cases, just like mocking, I set the state directly. In my real code, I don't use like that. Secondly, the two test cases sit in different files which means I have to call mountGk twice. Still I'm seeing the stores return the same state. Do you know anything about this behaviour?